# Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 19] No such device: '/home/site/wwwroot' in Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions (Linux OS, tied to app service plan) to run a Python function which at deployment I declared to be Python 3.8.

The function is triggered via timer.

When I run the function manually (using Functions --> Code+Test --> Test/Run screen in Azure portal), it works fine.

When the function is triggered via the timer, I receive the following error:

> Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 19] No such device: '/home/site/wwwroot' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 355, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 542, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/[my function name removed]/**init**.py", line 218, in main File "", line 991, in _find_and_load File "", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 914, in _find_spec File "", line 1342, in find_spec File "", line 1314, in _get_spec File "", line 1443, in find_spec File "", line 1483, in _fill_cache

The error directs me to line #218 in my init.py script, however, this line is only a comment, not actual code.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @BowmanZhu, the function is ~400 lines long, so sharing the entire thing isn't feasible, but I will see if I can pull out the relevant parts.